# Delimit string and put it in listbox

Tags: c#, regex, string, listbox

I have a string like:

```
one,one,one,one,two,two,two,two,three,three,three,three,four,four,four,four,...
```

and I'd like to delimit it after every fourth comma and store it into a list box, like this:

```
one,one,one,one,
two,two,two,two,
three,three,three,three,
four,four,four,four,
...
```

What should be appropriate way to do this? Should I supposed to use regex to somehow delimit this string?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linqless alternative;

```
int s = 0, n = 0, len = inputString.Length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputString[i] == ',' && ++n % 4 == 0 || i == len - 1)  {
        aListBox.Items.Add(inputString.Substring(s, i - s + 1));
        s = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This LINQ breaks your input into individual strings by delimiting on the comma, then uses an [index in the `Select` method](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/05/17/c.net-little-wonders-select-and-where-with-indexes.aspx) to group four items together at a time, then finally joins those four items into a single string again.

```
var input = "one,one,one,one,two,two,two,two,three,three,three,three";  // and so on

var result = input.Split(',')
                  .Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
                  .GroupBy(pair => pair.i / 4)
                  .Select(grp => string.Join(",", grp.Select(pair => pair.s)) + ",");
```

The result is a collection of strings, where the first one (based on your input) is "one,one,one,one,", then the second is "two,two,two,two," and so on...

[image]

From there, it's just a matter of setting it as the `DataSource`, `ItemsSource` or similar, depending on what technology you're using.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I'm not used to LINQ use so I decided to take Alex's reply as the answer.